# MySql - trying to import a database, get message 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

Tags: mysql

I installed MySql 4.1(because that what is running on my server), I got a file that is a dump of my database.  It is about 4.6 GB.

I put that file in same location as MySql.exe lives `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\bin`

Then I go to command line and type in:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p [database name] < mysqlDump.sql
```

I get message back  '`The system cannot find the file specified.'`

What file is it referring to? The mysqlDump.sql?

Even when I specify the full path to the mySqlDump.sql file, I get the same message.

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p [database name] < C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\bin\mysqlDump.sql
```

I'm running MySql 4.1 on Windows7

**update** found out my mistake. My folder was hiding file extensions. Somehow when I saved the file on my machine I gave it an extra .sql extension. So the file had a name of mysqlDump.sql.sql

Comment: Dont forget to press "solved" on best answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TAB key when you are starting typing mysqlDump... to ensure that your file is there and you have privileges for it.

Tab key in command line will complete filename or not.

This will give you some information if the file exists and if you have permissions to that file. Maybe it was created from other operating system user account and you have no read privileges.

> I put that file in same location as MySql.exe lives C:\Program
> Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\bin

This is not good idea, because regular operating system user accoung may have no privileges to write in Program Files directory.

To do it properly I would add `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\bin` to the PATH environment variable ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee537574(v=office.14)) with howto). After you do this you will be able to run MySQL executable files from anywhere you want (like your desktop or documents folder for example) without messing around in `Program Files`. You can place your working file at location where you have all privileges and work on it from the command line.

Answer (score 6):

You are probably not in the right directory when you make the call.

Go there:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\bin"
```

or specify the input file's absolute path:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p [database name] < "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\bin"
```

Comment: @dev try putting the dump file elsewhere then, like `C:\dump.sql`, and try again. Maybe the spaces in the file path are confusing mySQL.

Comment: You can add to PATH system variable your mysql bin directory path. After this you will be able access mysql.exe from any directory.

Comment: Use TAB key when you are starting typing mysqlDump... to ensure that your file is there. Tab key in command line will complete filename or not. Also you should check permissions on that file. Maybe its generated from other user account and you have no read privileges.

Comment: Okay dumbest mistake ever. My folder was hiding file extensions. Somehow when I saved the file on my machine I gave it an extra .sql extension. So the file had a name of mysqlDump.sql.sql

Comment: Im always using TAB key in commandline to avoid mistakes like that. I recommend this to you.