# Why is the system not able to find the specified file?

Tags: c#, mysql

So, I have this bit of code, and it would seem I am getting an error on the fourth line. The error specifically is "The system cannot find the file specified". Where did I go wrong, and how can I fix this bug?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=localhost;user id=root;database=localhost");
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Role from accounts Where Username='" + UserNameBox.Text + "' and Password='" + PasswordBox.Text +"'", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Maybe you have the wrong connection string? To what exactly are you trying to connect?

Comment: My MySQL database.

Comment: Do you allow `' OR Username='admin` as a password?

Comment: is your database really called "localhost"??

Comment: Yeah, but this is basically only a personal project right now; it is not on the 'net or anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394907/mysql-trying-to-import-a-database-get-message-the-system-cannot-find-the-fil